# How to return Optional<T> as JSON in the Spring @RestController?

Tags: spring-mvc, java-8, option-type

There is the code in the @RestController:

```
@GetMapping("update_odds")
public Optional<OddsJSON> updateOdds() {
   return eventService.updateOdds();
}
```

Result of this method in the browser:

```
{
present: true
}
```

Is it possible to configure Jackson mapper to output the value of Optional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just need to add to the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This dependency has been moved by Jackson. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8